# Move a canvas up and down - html5 / css3

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have created a canvas element by taking user inputs for the size and the colour.
I want to make the canvas move up and down the page continuously. How can I achieve this?
Below is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <script src="pol.js" >
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The following is the javascript file "pol.js" :

```
var h=prompt("Provide length of square");
var col=prompt("Provide the color");
document.write('<div id="float" ><canvas id="myCanvas" width="'+h+'" height="'+h+'" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"> </canvas> </div>');
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle=col;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,h,h);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "`move up and down the page continuously`"? Do you mean that you want the element to follow the user as they scroll through the page?

Comment: No, I mean it should animatedly bob up and down a fixed length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following CSS should smoothly move the canvas element between the top of the page and 500px down from it:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @keyframes moveabout {
        from { top: 0px; }
        to   { top: 500px; }
    }
    #float {
        position: absolute;
        animation: moveabout 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    }
</style>
```

For more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

If you want to move the element from the top to the bottom of the page you could use document.windowHeight to get the window's viewport height.